# How do I fix MYSQLI Fatal Call Error?

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I am using the latest version of Wordpress and the database is 7.0.  I recently installed a plugin and received a Fatal Error message regarding the mysql_escape_string.  I am new to this error and did research and I changed the mysql to mysqli, but am now receiving this message:

> Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /homepages/13/XXXXXX/htdocs/XXX/wp-content/themes/candidate/functions.php on line 59
>
> Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /homepages/13/XXXXXX/htdocs/XXX/wp-content/themes/candidate/functions.php on line 103

Here is the code that is displayed on these lines:
LINE 59 - 65:

```
if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
{
    $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
    if ($data -> full_content)
        {
            print stripslashes($data -> content);
        }
```

LINE 103:

```
$GLOBALS['WP_URL_CD'] = stripslashes( $wpdb -> get_var('SELECT `code` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'install_meta` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($super_url).'"') );
```

---

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Look at the manual for `mysqli_escape_string` because as the error states `expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`. It needs the connection string...or use the OOP syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter for `mysqli_escape_string` is db connection.
In **wordpress** you should use `esc_sql` instead of `mysqli_escape_string`.

Read more info https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andrej, your answer worked to solve the code error.  But, another code error popped up about headers.  After researching more, I decided to try just overwriting the functions.php file with another copy and that actually fixed everything.